# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: program compiles fine, but the error shows when it runs

Tags: java

```
public void traverseRowLR(String [] list, String [] key, String pool)
   { 
      pool = "left to right";
      ArrayList<Location> obj = new ArrayList<Location>();
      for(int i = 0; i<key.length; i++)
      {
         for(int a=0;a<list.length;a++)
            if(list[a].indexOf(key[i])>-1)
               finalList.add(new Location(key[i],a+1,list[a].indexOf(key[i]),pool));        
      }

   }
```

That above is the method. The error is on the line of the second for loop.

Heres another place the error is mentioned:

```
 public MazeAH(String [] key, String [][] wordBank)
   {
      maze = wordBank;
      answer = key; 
   }

 //other methods 

   public ArrayList<Location> solve()
   {  
      mergeRow(maze, rowWords);
      mergeCol(maze, colWords);   
      traverseRowLR(rowWords, answer, horizontal);
      traverseRowRL(rowWords, answer, horizontal);
      traverseRowTB(colWords, answer, vertical);
      traverseRowBT(colWords, answer, vertical);

      return finalList;
   }
```

The error is in the line:

```
traverseRowLR(rowWords, answer, horizontal);
```

Finally, heres the driver program, sorry if im posting too much code, im not sure what's necessary: The goal of this program is to merge rows and columns together into Strings, and then search for words in the "key" word bank. I originally completed this project using non-void methods, but my professor wants me to redo it with void methods.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SolveWordSearchAH
{

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

      String [][] letters = {{"e","p","l","i","r","q","k","o","s","a"},
                        {"u","k","i","e","s","y","x","c","n","f"},
                        {"c","p","o","z","g","f","q","a","y","r"},
                        {"p","e","m","c","z","a","n","t","e","i"},
                        {"g","u","g","q","t","a","b","r","h","e"},
                        {"g","i","q","v","b","e","d","b","s","s"},
                        {"c","o","f","f","e","e","i","l","r","q"},
                        {"h","r","e","t","a","w","b","d","e","l"},
                        {"y","q","o","k","w","v","p","x","h","z"},
                        {"c","d","n","t","f","q","k","b","p","w"}};

      String [] key = {"coffee", "water", "taco", "hershey", "fries"};
      //can have another key array if needed-depends on your implementation

      MazeAH m=new MazeAH(key, letters);
      ArrayList<Location> answer=m.solve();
      System.out.println(answer);

   }
}
```

My variables are declared here:

```
private ArrayList<Location> finalList = new ArrayList<Location>();
   private String [][] maze;
   private String [] answer;
   private String vertical="";
   private String horizontal = ""; 
   private String [] rowWords;
   private String [] colWords;
```

Here is the error in the compile log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MazeAH.mergeRow(MazeAH.java:117)
    at MazeAH.solve(MazeAH.java:26)
    at SolveWordSearchAH.main(SolveWordSearchAH.java:24)
```

Heres MergeRow:

```
 public void mergeRow(String[][] letters, String [] words)
   {
      String []temp = new String [letters.length];
      for(int i=0; i<letters.length; i++)
      {
         temp[i]="";
         for(int a=0; a<letters[0].length; a++)
         {
            temp[i]+=letters[i][a];
         }
      }
      for(int s = 0; s<temp.length; s++)
      {
      temp[s] = words[s];
      }

   }
```

Heres the updated trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MazeAH.mergeRow(MazeAH.java:117)
    at MazeAH.solve(MazeAH.java:26)
    at SolveWordSearchAH.main(SolveWordSearchAH.java:24)
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace of the error

Comment: I don't see rowWords or colWords declared anywhere - where do you define them?

Comment: I made updates to the post.

Comment: The stack trace says the error is in the mergeRow method, but I don’t see that method in your question.

Comment: As per the stacktrace, exception is in mergeRow method and not in traverseRowLR.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You declare rowWords and colWords but never assign anything to them. This means they will hold the default value of `null`, and any attempt to access array elements is going to fail.

I don't know how many elements you need to store in rowWords and colWords, but if  100 is enough you can initialize them with:

```
 public MazeAH(String [] key, String [][] wordBank)
   {
      maze = wordBank;
      answer = key; 
      rowWords = new String[100];
      colWords = new String[100];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

"The error is on the line of the second for loop", clearly refers to the line;

```
for(int a=0;a<list.length;a++)
```

[Although stack trace to support this statement is missing. Try to print the correct most meaningful part of the stack trace in your next question.]

Now, if this is throwing a NullPointerException, it means at run time of your code, the value of `list` is null.

You can easily check this by writing a `System.out.println(line);` before your loop.

Based on the little code you have shared, I can only say that this is a result of you sending a `null` value as `rowWords` in you `traverseRowLR` call.
Perhaps you are never initializing the variable `rowWords`

I hope this helps!